# UILabel Doesn't populate random strings chosen from NSMutable Array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to populate a UILabel with strings randomly chosen from an array. For some reason, the random choosing from array doesn't occur (the label always displays the first element of the array).

//.h file has declaration as follows

```
NSMutableArray *array;
```

//.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"abc", @"def", nil];


}
```

and then, I have a method called orientationPopulate that does this:

```
-(void)labelPopulate;
{
    int randomArrayIndex = arc4random() % array.count;
    //Setting the label's text
    _label.text = array[randomArrayIndex];
}
```

Based on the label displayed randomly, I would click buttons on the screen. So the label must keep changing each time. I do not know if I'm missing some link here. Can somebody help?

Comment: Did you debug into your method? Does your randomArrayIndex change?

Comment: Yeah, like I said before, the orientation is always the first value in the array. So the index is always 0. It doesnt change.

Comment: Is the method called multiple times? What code calls labelPopulate? Please add more code to your quesiton.

Comment: Your snippet [works fine](https://gist.github.com/alladinian/0937707e754539caf384). So the reason you see the same text on the label must be something else (perhaps `_label` is `nil` at that point?). You could add a breakpoint and examine both the random index & the label...

Comment: More code is necessary. Where is the label created? Is the label bound to your variable "_label"?

Comment: check you _label connection...

Comment: My _label is hooked up to the outlet correctly. When I run the app, the label must randomly select values from the array and use it. I will then tap on the button on the screen based on that. I want the label to keep selecting values from the array(not just when the app loads, so I cannot call the labelPopulate function from viewDidLoad). How can I make the label display random values each time, based on which I can tap a button? I mean, how can I write the function for this?

Comment: My question in simple terms is how do I dynamically keep changing the label?

Comment: Ok I guess I made a small mistake in the function call... Thanks for pointing that out to me. I have it up and running now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

randomArrayIndex is 0 or 1, it may not change every time you click the button

Comment: I would want it to keep changing everytime, from the time it loads on the screen. Based on what the label value is, I would click a button. I would not want the label to change values after I click the button. It is the other way round.

Comment: If only 2 values, it is simple to do. If many values, if the new value is equal to label.text label, randomly select the value again until they are not the same.